# What is the difference between assigning an instance variable before and after parameter?

Tags: java, function, oop, datamember

What is the difference between assigning a parameter to an instance variable? Why is it wrong when you write the parameter before the instance variable?

```
int variable; 

void set(int parameter)
{
    variable = parameter;
    parameter = variable; 
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to overwrite the local value of the passed `parameter`? It's not *wrong* per-se, but it's unusual.

Comment: Assignment to a parameter will compile, so it’s not wrong syntactically. How would you define wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case 1:

```
int variable;

void set(int parameter)
{
    variable = parameter;
}
```

Case 2:

```
int variable;

void set(int parameter)
{
    parameter = variable;
}
```

Both cases are correct by Java syntax, but case 2 has very little logical value...

The case 2 method parameter has a value and we need to use it. but before using this value, we change this by assigning *variable*,
so we lost the previous value.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a case of not understanding assignment, i.e., asking about the difference between

```
x = y;
```

and

```
y = x;
```

Assignment sets the left hand side variable equal to the value on the right hand side, so the action of the two is very very different.  The first changes `x` and leaves `y` unchanged; the second changes `y` and leaves `x` unchanged.

Comment: i already asked about the difference

Comment: I know; I was attempting to explain the difference in more general terms.